# Doctrine searching on Entity without any filters

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, symfony

I was wondering if there is a way to search in entity without applying any filters. For Example I would like to build a textfiled in my template where a ajax post method is calling to a controller with purpose searching the whole entity.

My code:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:QCE_SUBD')
        ->find('%'.$SearchParam.'%')
        ->getQuery();


    $DSUB = $user->getArrayResult();

    dump($DSUB);
```

I;m not sure how the function should be written, so if some one is willing to help it will be highly appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

You should just create a function that return a JsonResponse with an array of your result.

```
// In your controller

/**                                                                                   
 * @Route("/ajax_action")
 */
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)    
{
    // Get the posted parameter from your ajax call
    $searchParam = $request->get('searchParam');

    // Request your entity
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:QCE_SUBD')
        ->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('q.username LIKE :searchParam')
        ->orWhere('q.otherColumn LIKE :searchParam')
        ->setParameter('searchParam', '%'.$searchParam.'%')
        ->getQuery();

    // Check if it's an ajax call
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {         
        return new JsonResponse($user->getArrayResult();
    }

    // Return an error
    throw new \Exception('Wrong call!');
}
```

For the search part you need to implement a **full text search**, here is a tutorial on how to implement it :
http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/90/how-to-implement-fulltext-search-mysql-with-doctrine-and-symfony-3

***P.S :*** You should be sure of what you need in your query. If you want it to be scalable, you should take a look at better search engine method as ElasticSearch or Solr.

Comment: davidbonachera Thank you for your answer, but I receiving this error:Error: Call to a member function getQuery() on a non-object,, Any idea

Comment: I edit the query builder, i'm not familiar with it, your question was how to create the query, or more how to create the controller ? For the query you can easier use the doctrine querybuilder, or directly request with a SQL query.

Comment: My point was, how I can create a query builder without specifying all the all the columns of the entity, But instead the query builder check all of the m by default. I hope you can understand  my question. Thanks again for the support!!!

Comment: Maybe you can update your question and told us which kind of field you want to search for. I will advice you to look more about a fulltext search if you want to look all the different text columns matching a LIKE query without specifying those (cf link in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can inspire yourself from the following function. It iterates dynamically through all fields of the entity and depending on the type of the field a condition is applied to the query builder:

```
/**
 * Creates the query builder used to get the results of the search query
 * performed by the user in the "search" view with a given "keyword".
 *
 * @param array       $entityConfig
 * @param string      $searchQuery
 * @param string|null $sortField
 * @param string|null $sortDirection
 * @param string|null $dqlFilter
 *
 * @return DoctrineQueryBuilder
 */
public function createSearchQueryBuilder(array $entityConfig, $searchQuery, $sortField = null, $sortDirection = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{
    /* @var EntityManager */
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManagerForClass($entityConfig['class']);
    /* @var DoctrineQueryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('entity')
        ->from($entityConfig['class'], 'entity')
    ;

    $queryParameters = array();
    foreach ($entityConfig['search']['fields'] as $name => $metadata) {
        $isNumericField = in_array($metadata['dataType'], array('integer', 'number', 'smallint', 'bigint', 'decimal', 'float'));
        $isTextField = in_array($metadata['dataType'], array('string', 'text', 'guid'));

        if ($isNumericField && is_numeric($searchQuery)) {
            $queryBuilder->orWhere(sprintf('entity.%s = :exact_query', $name));
            // adding '0' turns the string into a numeric value 
            $queryParameters['exact_query'] = 0 + $searchQuery;
        } elseif ($isTextField) {
            $searchQuery = strtolower($searchQuery);

            $queryBuilder->orWhere(sprintf('LOWER(entity.%s) LIKE :fuzzy_query', $name));
            $queryParameters['fuzzy_query'] = '%'.$searchQuery.'%';

            $queryBuilder->orWhere(sprintf('LOWER(entity.%s) IN (:words_query)', $name));
            $queryParameters['words_query'] = explode(' ', $searchQuery);
        }
    }

    if (0 !== count($queryParameters)) {
        $queryBuilder->setParameters($queryParameters);
    }

    if (!empty($dqlFilter)) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere($dqlFilter);
    }

    if (null !== $sortField) {
        $queryBuilder->orderBy('entity.'.$sortField, $sortDirection ?: 'DESC');
    }

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

The [source code](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Search/QueryBuilder.php) comes from the [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle).

Comment: COiL thanks for the answer, but I think my problem is even simpler. What I want to achieve is check the whole entity, I know that I can specify all the filed in the entity, but I thinkn that will be a loooooot of work and extra line! So, for example I search <123> the result from the doctine should return all the any data taht contains <123>. Doesn't matter what filed.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the purpose of this function. Or you should have a look at elasticsearch.